# UTF-8 File data to ANSII

Tags: c#

I have UTF-8 files (with Swedish äåö characters). I read those as:

```
List<MyData> myDataList = new List<MyData>();
string[] allLines = File.ReadAllLines(csvFile[0], Encoding.Default);

foreach (string line in allLines)
{
  MyData myData = new MyData();
  string[] words = line.Split(";");

  myData.ID = words[0];
  myData.Name = word[1];
  myData.Age = words[2];
  myData.Date = words[3];
  myData.Score = words[4];

  //Do something...
  myDataList.Add(myData);
}

StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
foreach (string data in myDataList)
{
   sb.AppendLine(string.Format("{0},{1},{2},{3},{4}",
       data.ID,
       data.Name,
       data.Age,
       data.Date,
       data.Score));
}       

File.WriteAllText("output.txt", sb.ToString(), Encoding.ASCII);
```

I get output.txt file in ansii but not with Swedish characters. Can someone help me to know how can I save file data from UTF-8 to Ansii? Thanks.

Comment: Currently you are writing the file in ASCII, which is very limited and not capable of showing those "swedish" characters. I would recommend to try this : System.IO.File.WriteAllText(path, text, Encoding.GetEncoding(28594));

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What you *probably* mean by "ANSII"¹ is the codepage [Windows-1252](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1252), used by most Western European countries.

At the moment, you are reading the file in your system default encoding, which is probably Windows-1252, and writing it as [`ASCII`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII), which defines only the first 128 characters and does not include any non-English characters (such as äåö):

```
string[] allLines = File.ReadAllLines(csvFile[0], Encoding.Default);
...
File.WriteAllText("output.txt", sb.ToString(), Encoding.ASCII);
```

**This is both wrong.** If you want to convert your file **from UTF-8 to Windows-1252**, you need to *read as UTF-8* and *write as Windows 1252*, i.e.

```
string[] allLines = File.ReadAllLines(csvFile[0], Encoding.UTF8);
...
File.WriteAllText("output.txt", sb.ToString(), new Encoding(1252));
```

---

¹ It is spelled `ANSI`; but even that is not entirely correct (quote from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1252)):

> Historically, the phrase “ANSI Code Page” (ACP) is used in Windows to refer to various code pages considered as native. The intention was that most of these would be ANSI standards such as ISO-8859-1. Even though Windows-1252 was the first and by far most popular code page named so in Microsoft Windows parlance, the code page has never been an ANSI standard. Microsoft-affiliated bloggers now state that “The term ANSI as used to signify Windows code pages is a historical reference, but is nowadays a misnomer that continues to persist in the Windows community.”

Comment: Yes thats what I meant by ANSII, but your code File.WriteAllText("output.txt", sb.ToString(), new Encoding(1252)); saves the output file in UTF-8. I want in ANSII!

Comment: You just need to use Codepage Latin-4 as described in my answer. Best regards

Comment: I'm quite sure `new Encoding(1252)` makes it save in Windows-1252, as Heinzi says, not UTF-8. What makes you think it saves it as UTF-8? Latin-4 is "Northern European", but that refers to Estonia, Lithuania, Greenland etc., not Scandinavia (although the Scandinavian characters are included). You'd want Latin-1. But Windows-1252 is a superset of Latin-1 in the first place, so you might as well stick with this answer.

Comment: @mrd: Please have a look at my answer. I habe edited the code to use the codepage [ISO 8859-13](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8859-13)

Comment: @mrd: Please have a look at my edit. You were *reading* the file wrongly.

Answer (score 1):

Currently you are writing the file in ASCII, which is very limited and not capable of showing those "swedish" characters. I would recommend to try this :

```
System.IO.File.WriteAllText(path, text, Encoding.GetEncoding(28603));
```

This writes the file in ANSI encoding with codepage Latin-4. I would recommend you the wikipedia article: [ISO 8859](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8859)

Comment: System.IO.File.WriteAllText(path, text, Encoding.GetEncoding(28594)); It saves Swedish characters in strange way...

Comment: Then you will have to take a look at the other codepages. One will include the character set you need. The problem is that there are no "swedish" characters. You will have to be a little bit more specific.

Comment: Could you please try encoding 28603.

Comment: File.WriteAllText(csvFile, sb.ToString(), Encoding.GetEncoding(28603)); does not work! It has wrong Swedish characters.

Comment: It would really help a lot if you could be a little bit more specific on the characters you have a problem with. Give us an example!

Comment: I have name 'BRÄNNKAMMAREN 4 AB' in input csv file which is in UTF-8. When I try to save in ANSII using your code it saves it as 'BRA¥NNKAMMAREN 4 AB'.

Comment: If I see this right that a with the dots above is not swedish it's actually german.

Comment: It is also Swedish :) äåö are also Swedish characters.