# Replace() working with hex value

Tags: c#, .net, hex, culture

I would like to use the Replace() method but using hex values instead of string value.

I have a programm in C# who write text file.

I don't know why, but when the programm write the '°' (-> Number) it's wrotten Â° ( in hex : C2 B0 instead of B0).

I just would like to patch it, in order to corect this.

Is it possible to do re place in order to replace C2B0 by B0 ? How doing this ?

Thanks a lot :)

Comment: Why doesn't `Replace()` work? `yourString.Replace((char)0xC2B0, (char)0xB0);`

Comment: It's not clear what you mean by "in hex" here. If you mean that's the data in the text file when considering it as *binary*, you should probably be treating the data as binary to start with. My guess is that you don't actually mean [U+C2B0](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/c2b0/index.htm).

Comment: this is not a candidate for replacements, but an encoding (Unicode <> ANSI) issue. which application renders this as "Â°"? could you show a minimal example of the code that writes to the file?

Comment: The program simply write a DataTable content to a texte with the File.WriteAllText().

Comment: so does the datatable cell have the hangul seuls character 슰 in it, or where does the 0xC2 byte come from? how do you serialize datatable contents into a string? I think this is the task here, not patching the result, but finding out where it comes from. show the relevant C# source.

Comment: Whenever you see an accented A then you should always immediately think "utf8 !"  And yes, the utf-8 encoding for the `°` character is indeed 0xC3 0xB0.  Don't fix it, utf-8 is good, just make sure that whatever program you use to look at the file understands that it is utf-8.  Which may require generating a BOM, pass `new UTF8Encoding(true)` to the StreamWriter constructor.  If you really, *really* hate it then pass Encoding.Default.

Comment: Problem is the file is reading by another programm by another compagny...and they cannot changer their encoding reader. So i have to fix it.

Comment: I tried to add "Encoding.UTF8" in the File.WriteAllText() and same problem. If i try the yourString.Replace((char)0xC2B0, (char)0xB0), same issue :( No changes.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is the best solution for your problem but if you want a replace function for a string using hex values this will work:

```
var newString = HexReplace(sourceString, "C2B0", "B0");


    private static string HexReplace(string source, string search, string replaceWith) {
        var realSearch = string.Empty;
        var realReplace = string.Empty;

        if(search.Length % 2 == 1) throw new Exception("Search parameter incorrect!");

        for (var i = 0; i < search.Length / 2; i++) {
            var hex = search.Substring(i * 2, 2);
            realSearch += (char)int.Parse(hex, System.Globalization.NumberStyles.HexNumber);
        }
        for (var i = 0; i < replaceWith.Length / 2; i++) {
            var hex = replaceWith.Substring(i * 2, 2);
            realReplace += (char)int.Parse(hex, System.Globalization.NumberStyles.HexNumber);
        }

        return source.Replace(realSearch, realReplace);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

C# strings are Unicode. When they are written to a file, an encoding must be applied. The default encoding used by `File.WriteAllText` is [utf-8 with no byte order mark](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/io/file.cs,851).

The two-byte sequence 0xC2B0 is the representation of the ° degree sign U+00B0 codepoint [in utf-8](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/00b0/index.htm).

To get rid of the 0xC2 part, apply a different encoding, for example latin-1:

```
var latin1 = Encoding.GetEncoding(1252);
File.WriteAllText(path, text, latin1);
```

To address the "hex replace" idea of the question: Best practice to remove the utf-8 leading byte from existing files would be to do a `ReadAllText` with utf-8, followed by a `WriteAllText` as shown above (or stream chunking if the files are too big to read to memory as a whole).

Single-byte character encodings cannot represent all Unicode characters, so substitution will happen for any such character in your DataTable.

The rendition as Â° must be blamed on the viewer/editor you are using to display the file.

Further reading: https://stackoverflow.com/a/17269952/1132334